# Confidence Interval

Tags: statistics

After taking 90 observations, you construct a 90% CI for μ . You are told that your interval is 3 times too wide.(i.e. your interval is 3 timers wider than what was required. You sample size should have been. (a)30 (b) 270 (c) 810 (d) 10

The correct answer is c. But why is C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the endpoints of a confidence interval for a population mean $\mu$ has endpoints $\bar x \pm A \dfrac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $A$ is a number you'd find in a table of values of the t-distribution or the normal distribution, where $n$ is the sample size.  Its length would then be some number divided by the square root of $n$.  If you want to make the length $1/3$ as big, you'd need to make the denominator $3$ times as big.  So you need to make $\sqrt{n}$ three times as big.  That means $n$ must be $9$ times as big, since $\sqrt{9}=3$.